# C# WPF ComboBox Auto switch number

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

How can i manage auto switch number in ComboBox in short simple way?

[image: Problem example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add separate properties in your ViewModel and separate ComboBoxes in the view, then manipulate the values when a value changes in the ViewModel, but this is cumbersome, and involves a lot of work when you add a new ComboBox (value).

A better approach is to create a custom collection that handles the changes:

```
public class ValueHolder<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, _value))
            {
                T old = _value;
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                OnValueChanged(old, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public ValueHolder()
    {
    }

    public ValueHolder(T value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs<T>> ValueChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnValueChanged(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        var h = ValueChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, new ValueChangedEventArgs<T>(oldValue, newValue));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

public class ValueChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T OldValue { get; set; }
    public T NewValue { get; set; }

    public ValueChangedEventArgs(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        this.OldValue = oldValue;
        this.NewValue = newValue;
    }
}

public class MyCollection<T> : Collection<ValueHolder<T>>
{
    public void Add(T i)
    {
        this.Add(new ValueHolder<T>(i));
    }

    private void AddChangeHandler(ValueHolder<T> item)
    {
        item.ValueChanged += item_ValueChanged;
    }

    private void RemoveChangeHandler(ValueHolder<T> item)
    {
        item.ValueChanged -= item_ValueChanged;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, ValueHolder<T> item)
    {
        AddChangeHandler(item);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        RemoveChangeHandler(this[index]);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            RemoveChangeHandler(item);
        }
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, ValueHolder<T> item)
    {
        RemoveChangeHandler(this[index]);
        AddChangeHandler(item);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }

    private void item_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs<T> e)
    {
        ValueHolder<T> v = (ValueHolder<T>)sender;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this[i] == v)
                continue;
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(this[i].Value, e.NewValue))
            {
                this[i].Value = e.OldValue;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then define your ViewModel like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyCollection<int> _values;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _values = new MyCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    }

    public MyCollection<int> Values
    {
        get { return _values; }
    }
}
```

and in your xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}" Margin="10">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Value}" Margin="5">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <Int32Collection >1,2,3,4,5</Int32Collection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is a lot of code! But does the task nicely, and also is very maintainable.

Comment: nice! but what about in a multiple or separated ComboBox in xaml?

Comment: this code works great.. but not its not fit on my xaml i have 5 separated combobox coz I want to get each value and save it on my database.. is there any other approach for separated ComboBox?

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this in that way. You should present the user swappable user controls which user can drag and drop, changing order with the mouse.

Your solution is not that good, but if you still want to do this, then in combobox selectitem event look through other comboboxes with that value and change it to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch values in your data model. As a result wpf controls will be updated when properties of the data model are changed.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <model:DataModel x:Key="MyModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{StaticResource MyModel}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        #region Construction and Initialization

        public DataModel()
        {
            var elements = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
            Items = new List<ItemsModel>
                {
                    new ItemsModel(elements, 1),
                    new ItemsModel(elements, 2),
                    new ItemsModel(elements, 3),
                    new ItemsModel(elements, 4),
                    new ItemsModel(elements, 5)
                };

            foreach (var itemsModel in Items)
            {
                itemsModel.PropertyChanged += SelectedItemChanged;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public List<ItemsModel> Items { get; private set; }

        private void SelectedItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedItem")
            {
                var model = sender as ItemsModel;
                Debug.Assert(model != null, "model != null");
                int pos = Items.IndexOf(model) + 1;
                Items[model.SelectedItem - 1].SelectedItem = pos;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ItemsModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Construction and Initialization

        public ItemsModel(IEnumerable<int> items, int selectedItem)
        {
            Items = items;
            _selectedItem = selectedItem;
        }

        #endregion

        public int SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedItem != value)
                {
                    _selectedItem = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                }
            }
        }

        private int _selectedItem;

        public IEnumerable<int> Items { get; private set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show some sample code?

Comment: Added the code example.